# getting reverted with reason string 'SWAP_CALL_FAILED' while trying back sell unitymeta Token

Tags: bsc, pancakeswap, 0x, api

```
 const unityMeta = '0xca861e289f04cB9C67fd6b87ca7EAFa59192f164';
 const WBNB = '0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c';
```

const params = {

```
        sellToken: unityMeta, 
        buyToken: WBNB, 
        sellAmount: amountIn, 

 
        // ...(FORKED ? {} : { takerAddress: taker}),            // takerAddress: '$USER_TAKER_ADDRESS', //Address that will make the trade
      }
     
      const quote =  await axios.get(
        `https://bsc.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?${qs.stringify(params)}`,  { headers} 
      );
```

successfully able to swap from wbnb -=> unityMeta but fail at unityMeta -=> wbnb